# Crystal report conditional section suppress

Tags: postgresql, crystal-reports

I've made a crystal report which has a section with name "detail d", and would like to suppress this section if the field `"stock_gift"` is empty (i.e. "")

I've set the condition in the `section expert` using below condition:

```
(trim({gift.stock_gift}) = "" or isnull({gift.stock_gift}))
```

But the section isn't suppressed, I checked the database whether the field is an empty string and it shows it's an empty string:

[image]

Is there anything wrong with the formula that caused the section unable to suppress?

Comment: try `(trim({gift.stock_gift}) = ''`

Comment: The result is still the same...:(

Comment: can show your `crystal report` design where your doing this suppress??

Comment: @Winged Panther I'm doing this in visual studio: Right click report => report => section expert, I put the formula in "Suppress display"

Comment: Try just {gift.stock_gift} = "" or .... without trim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that {gift.stock_gift} contains the empty string and NOT a null value? If it's a null then your suppression formula won't work correctly as it is; you need to either swap the order of your boolean statements like this:

```
isnull({gift.stock_gift}) or trim({gift.stock_gift}) = ""
```

Or get rid of everything except for the `isnull()` check. The reason for this is that if CR encounters a null value in a formula and it's not handled via `isnull()` as the *very first thing* in the formula, then that formula will produce an error exception and will not continue to be evaluated.